# AppleScript - replace substring in image names right after exporting them with Pixelmator and overwriting old images

Tags: applescript, pixelmator

After opening and editing images with Pixelmator pro I use this script:

```
tell application "Pixelmator Pro"
    set exportLocation to choose folder with prompt "Please select where you'd like export the images:"
    repeat (number of documents) times
        export the front document to file ((exportLocation as text) & (name of the front document) & ".jpg") as JPEG with properties {compression factor:85}
        close the front document without saving
    end repeat
end tell
```

to export them to the directory where the original images are.

The original image names are `abc.jpg`, `def.jpg`, `ghi.jpg` and after export it creates new images with those names: `abc.pxd.jpg`, `def.pxd.jpg`, `ghi.pxd.jpg`

How can I save the JPGs under their old name (`abc.jpg`, `def.jpg`, `ghi.jpg`) and overwrite the existing file?

Comment: Please take a moment to review [How to Ask a Good Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help].  Thus far, you”ve only described what you’ve done, not what you’ve tried and need assistance with.

Comment: >>>> I don't want those .pxd but preserving the old names overwriting the old images <<<<<

Comment: Things which may be clear for you may be far from clear for others, that's why comments are used to clarify questions. Please do not attack people for adding comments, try to improve the question instead.

Comment: Having said that: From what  I gather, you want to use Applescript to export the current images in Pixelmator into their original location with the original name (so an open `foo.jpg` gets exported to `foo.jpg` in the folder the original was opened from), correct? And the issue currently is that `name of the front document` is `foo.pxd`?

Comment: Yeah that's what I need to achieve and and that's the problem, the original foo.jpg which I edit and then export becomes foo.pxd.jpg but I want to delete the old foo.jpg and replace it with the new edited image and this should have the same name

Comment: So you need to take `name of the front document` and remove the `.pxd` part, most likely a simple string manipulation operation.